# C# Thread's state and "Sleep"

Tags: c#, thread-state

I'm trying to get a .NET thread state.
For this I check the `ProcessThread.ThreadState` property.
However when I use `Thread.Sleep` on that thread and check its state with `Process Explorer` - I see that it's in "Wait: Delay Exectuion", while my ThreadState is still "Running".
How can that be?

Comment: Can you try calling `Refresh` on the `Process` object before accessing `ThreadState`?

Comment: Are you doing this for debugging purposes? [`ThreadState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate.aspx): "Thread state is only of interest in debugging scenarios. Your code should never use thread state to synchronize the activities of threads."

Comment: @mikez: I did call "Refresh" on that process, but I kept a copy of that ProcessThread and looked at it instead of the new one, because I thought it will be refreshed too. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. thanks :)

Comment: The .NET ThreadState doesn't have anything to do with the operating system's thread state.  Sleep() is just a plain method as far as .NET is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Process` class caches properties on first access, so you will probably need to call the `Refresh` method to get an updated `ThreadState`. It seems that the `ProcessThread` objects (from the `ProcessThreads` property) are not attached to the parent `Process`, and the values it contains are not updated when `Refresh` is called. You will need to go through the `Process` object again.

Something like:

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessByName("MyProcess);

while(true)
{
  p.Refresh();
  Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessThreads[0].ThreadState);
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```